# No funcionan las modificaciones en Vue

Tags: php, javascript, laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

Los archivos `.vue` que están en la carpta `resources/assets/js/components` son los componentes del sistema. Me pasa que cuando edito alguno de esos componentes, en la vista no surge ninguna modificación.

archivo: `resources/assets/js/app.js`

```
require('./bootstrap');

import VueResource from 'vue-resource'
import Vodal from 'vodal';
import "vodal/common.css";
import "vodal/door.css";

// chartjs package
import "chart.js/dist/Chart.bundle.js"
// vue-charts package
require('hchs-vue-charts');
require('vue2-dropzone');
Vue.use(VueCharts);

Vue.use(VueResource);

Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = window.Laravel.csrfToken;

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */


Vue.component(Vodal.name, Vodal);
Vue.component('grid', require('./components/Grid.vue'));
Vue.component('location_grid', require('./components/ProductLocation.vue'));
Vue.component('date', require('./components/datepicker.vue'));
Vue.component('prod', require('./components/Select2Prod.vue'));
Vue.component('locs_list', require('./components/Select2Locs.vue'));
Vue.component('select2', require('./components/Select2.vue'));
Vue.component('item', require('./components/TRComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('item-location', require('./components/TRLocationComponent.vue'));
Vue.component('vtable', require('./components/Table.vue'));
Vue.component('upload', require('./components/ProductUpload.vue'));
Vue.component('avatarupload', require('./components/AvatarUpload.vue'));
```

archivo: `views/users/view_users.blade.pbp`

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('report')

@endsection
@section('title')
    {!! env('COMPANY_NAME') !!} | @lang('user.Users')
@endsection

@section('heading')
    @lang('user.Users')
@endsection

@section('content')
    <div id="app">
        <vtable url="user/items/filter" :columns="columns" :filters="filters"></vtable>
    </div>

@endsection

@section('jquery')
    <script>
        new Vue({
            el: '#app',
            data: {
                columns: [

                    {
                        "name": "name",
                        "title": "User",
                        "sortField": "name",
                        "visible": true
                    }, {
                        "name": "email",
                        "title": "Email",
                        "sortField": "Email",
                        "visible": true
                    }, {
                        "name": "department.name",
                        "title": "Department",
                        "sortField": "department",
                        "visible": true
                    },

                    {
                        name: '__component:custom-actions',
                        title: 'Actions',
                        titleClass: 'text-center',
                        dataClass: 'text-center'
                    }
                ],
                filters: [

                ]

            },
            methods: {}
        });
    </script>
@endsection
```

Todo lo que yo modifiqué en `'./components/Table.vue'`, no surge efecto

Comment: Aun después de reiniciar el servicio no surten efecto? Genera algún error?

Comment: no, ningún error, todo funciona bien. lo unico es que no se puede modificar nada, todo queda igual cuando edito algun archivo... como si fuese una especie de caché.. pero no es cache

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que los cambios surtan efecto tenés que:
1- Ejecutar en **consola** `npm install` para installar los paquetes de **package.json**
2- Despues tenés que ejecutar `npm run`, `npm run dev` o `npm run watch` (este ultimo es útil cuando estas modificando los componentes y probándolos inmediatamente)

Comment: lo intenté y nadaªª pero sigo probando, se que los tiros van por ahí

Comment: Así lo solucioné, me faltaba instalar algunas cosas en el npm

Answer (score 2):

en vez de utilizar el script en la vista, incorporá lo siguiente al final de `app.js`

```
const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});
```

y enviá los datos desde el controlador

```
$columns = [];
$filters = [];
return view('users.view_users')->with('columns',$columns)->with('filters',$filters);
```

En la vista no tendrías que agregar la etiqueta `script`

Comment: la instancia de vue funciona perfectamente en la vista, el problema es editar los componentes .vue

Comment: Que es lo que modificaste en Table.vue?

Comment: cuando hacés `npm run` no te tira ningun error?  
Podrías poner el codigo de `layouts.master` y de `webpack.mix.js`  
Si sigue sin funcionar probablemente esta sin configurar el webpack o estas llamando mal los assets